# Read list of applications from the Applications folder on Mac using Qt

Tags: qt, macos, macos-carbon

I want to read list of applications from the Applications folder on Mac using Qt or Carbon.
I am not sure how to do this. So any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: There isn't one true Applications folder; /Applications has sub-folders, and people can keep their applications anywhere, including ~/Applications. (I keep mine on an entire other partition.) You might consider using Spotlight instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to get the Applications dir and then use the Qt helpers to iterate over it - i.e QDir, and finding bundles as directories whose names end in '.app'. Here's some code to get a QDir from a folder reference type - there are many similar constants, to get the desktop/trash/library folders. The 'domain' value is important - for many folders (eg, Library) there's a per-user version as well as global and network versions. FileVault can complicate things further.

The documentation on FSFindFolder should make things clearer, and there's examples all over the web.

```
static QDir applicationsDir()
{
    short domain = kOnAppropriateDisk;
    FSRef ref;
    OSErr err = FSFindFolder(domain, kApplicationsFolderType, false, &ref);
    if (err) {
        return QDir();
    }

    return QDir(getFullPath(ref));
}

/*
    Constructs a full unicode path from a FSRef.
*/
static QString getFullPath(const FSRef &ref)
{
    QByteArray ba(2048, 0);
    if (FSRefMakePath(&ref, reinterpret_cast<UInt8 *>(ba.data()), ba.size()) == noErr)
        return QString::fromUtf8(ba).normalized(QString::NormalizationForm_C);
    return QString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list a directory using either [the opendir(3) and readdir(3) functions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/opendir.3.html) or the FSOpenIterator and FSGetCatalogInfoBulk functions from [the Core Services File Manager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/).